# jQuery - Cycle with slight difference

Tags: jquery, cycle

I have used the cycle plugin and various others but I don't think they will work in this example.  I have a latest news section which is 1 line.  eg:

Latest News - This is the information shown

I want to cycle through the various news updates.  The slight difference is I want the updates to slideRight (to hide) then the next update slideLeft(to show).  This way the width is constantly changing and the latest news heading should move left and right as the updates collapse and expands (with variable width depending on text because it is inline).  Therefore position absolute and fixed width solutions don't help.

Im guessing its reasonably simple but Im not sure how.  I could start with the CSS and define only the first p to be shown.  Then in jQuery slideright current, then next() slideleft?

http://pastebin.com/2qCQeBMF
http://pastebin.com/ERU9K8hC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a series of animations and then cycle back at the end

```
/**
 * Method to animate the news feed
 */
function scrollNews() {
    // If latest news is not being hovered upon
    if (!$('.latestnews').hasClass('hover')) {
        // Get the currently visible update
        var currentUpdate = $('.theupdates').find('p').filter(':visible').first();
        // Get the next update
        var nextUpdate = currentUpdate.next();
        // If there are no next updates
        if (nextUpdate.length === 0) {
            // Get the first update and set it as the next update
            nextUpdate = $('.theupdates').find('p').filter(':first-of-type');
        }
        // Animate the current update out
        currentUpdate.hide('slow', function () {
            // Animate the next update in
            nextUpdate.show('slow', function () {
                // Delay a little bit and then recursively call this method
                window.setTimeout(scrollNews, 2000);
            });
        });
    } else {
        // Delay a little bit and then recursively call this method
        window.setTimeout(scrollNews, 2000);
    }
}

// Handle hover over news
$('.latestnews').on({
    'mouseover': function (e) {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    },
    'mouseout': function (e) {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    }
});

// Start animation
scrollNews();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zNrd/1/)

Comment: Ahh that is almost perfect.  I changed the animations to show and hide (more what I want, but would rather a slide right and left).  Also I switched the CSS so the P and the Strong are display:block because when jQuery shows it changes to block which pushes it below.  Only problem is the cycle stops after one run-through, how to repeat it continuously?

Comment: @Michael Did you look at the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vAutP/3/) example at the end? It should cycle continuously.

Comment: Here is the fiddle which is the effect I was aiming for.  Slight difference is the hide/show.  If I change to the jQuery ui and use slide direction is causes problems and the text jumps below for some reason.  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vAutP/9/)

Comment: For some reason the animations still stop on the last item, despite the fact I copied the jscript straight from the updated fiddle.  Link to in action [here](http://intelligentstudios.co.uk/ElegentHosting/index.html).

Comment: @Michael The `:first-of-type` selector was introduced in jQuery 1.9. You are using version 1.7.2. Since the browser doesn't recognize it, there is a JavaScript error. If you want to use the older jQuery version, changing it to `:first-child` should also work.

Comment: Ahh, it was the jQuery version.  Works with the latest, although now the animation is a bit choppy.  EDIT:  Thanks, seems to be the padding on the P which is being collapsed which caused the jerkyness.

Comment: @Michael That is apparently a bug in jQuery 1.9.0. I believe [jQuery 1.9.1](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js) fixes the problem ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zNrd/)). Also, if you found my answer and subsequent comments helpful, could you please either upvote or accept the answer.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you.  The only slight difference is the show/hide instead of slide right and left but its barely noticeable.

Comment: @Michael I updated my answer to handle stop on hover. For anything else, I recommend starting a new question. This is considered an extended discussion on SO, and this site discourages having them in comments.